# MDX object not found in cube

Tags: mdx, olap-cube, mondrian

I have districts with areas. and i'm trying to fetch data from my cube. the problem is:

1. i add new area to district in database.
2. the data in cube is recalculated only once a day. so rigth after i have added new area it will be not present in my cube.
3. and when i try to get info from cube i get the error 'MDX object '[ATD].[Area].&[6007d9a7-a137-4bba-9d72-0020ee5d2db0]' not found in cube'
   after the cube is recalculated everything is ok.

how can i fight this error?

```
with member [Measures].[District]   
     member [Measures].[Area]       
     member [Measures].[AreaID]                         
select
                    {
                         [Measures].[District],
                         [Measures].[Area], 
                         [Measures].[AreaID]

                    }  on columns,
                    {
                          {{[MyDimension].[Area].&[6007d9a7-a137-4bba-9d72-0020ee5d2db0]}}
                    } on rows
                    from SomeCube
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the `ignoreInvalidMembers` property to true.

You can find more information on [Mondrian's configuration page](http://mondrian.pentaho.com/documentation/configuration.php).

Comment: I use tomcat and I put a mondrian.properties file in bin directory of tomcat but it seems it's not being used.

Comment: i have solved the problem: just put the file in \mondrian\WEB-INF\classes\